# How do you make text automatically contrast with a gradient background?

Tags: css, html, background-color, linear-gradients

I would like to have a backaground transition from one color to another, however this washes out some of the text. Is there a way to make the text automatically adjust to the background? Preferably using only CSS?

I've tried using a "mix-blend-mode:difference" solution from another forum, but that did nothing to the text.

```
    .container{
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, black);
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
body{
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
}
```

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pLt8joe/)

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797638/change-color-of-text-responding-to-background-color/52797690#52797690

Comment: These are not practical solutions for me. The text shadow makes the text look awful and I am not using an image background, so I can't make the background darker. The gradient is supposed to blend from the default white background to the darker color.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the gradient background on parent container. And use the reverse background gradient for text with `text-fill-color: transparent` and `background-clip: text`.

```
.container{
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, white);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
body{
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, black);
}
```

You can test it here.. http://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/hpbwo4q7/

P.S. - At some point it will match the color (grey) with the background color.

:)

Comment: I saw a similar solution, but obviously the middle portion where the gray blends with the gray is a huge problem.