# White Text color and White image background color issue

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic4

I have an image and text as like below.

[image]

*.html*

```
<div [ngClass]="cssDivClass" (click)="goToNextPage(data)">
  <img [src]="data?.image" class="image" tappable>
  <div class="caption" [ngClass]="ionTextUppercase">{{data?.name }}</div>
</div>
```

*.scss*

```
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}
```

My question here is How can I handle this text color (i.e. white) with the White background image? What kind of CSS trick should I use here? I need white color text here since most of the other images have dark colors. So how can I handle this thing in a generic way?

Comment: consider text-shadow

Comment: Can you please give a simple example? @TemaniAfif

Comment: I finding it ... answered a similar question

Comment: How do other designers handle that problem? Have you noticed they use usually a dark transparent gradient layer or text shadow. There's also a difference effect you can use (like photoshops) in CSS but not super supported... But the question is too broad.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52797690/8620333 (if it solves your issue I will close as duplicate)

Comment: This is a design question, not a code question.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe text-shadow may help you to have a good contrast also in light background.

You can also consider a prominent color extraction plugin to set an alternative text color if the background is light:
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/403/top-5-best-image-color-extraction-javascript-and-jquery-plugins

You can consider also to use:

```
mix-blend-mode: difference;
```

and use text-shadow only for browser that not support this property

https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode

```css
body{
  background:#fff;
  font-size:30px;
}
.container{
  transform: translateZ(0);
  will-change: opacity;
    background: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/any/grayscale")
    no-repeat left / cover;
}

.shadow {
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;
}

.blend {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="shadow">text-shadow</div>

<div class="blend">difference</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try a shadow on the white text, this way it will show up on dark and light photographs.

```
text-shadow: #fc0 1px 0 10px;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow

Another trick is to use a semi transparent div below the text, so that no matter what the background is, the text will be visible.  It would look like this:

https://divibooster-6d4b.kxcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/divi-theme-semi-transparent-background.png

Still another possibility would be to use Javascript.  If your photo is a 'light' photo, change your text's css class to 'color: black'.  If it is a 'dark' photo, change your text's css class to 'color: white'.