# Is there a way to make a background for my <p> attribute so that I can see the text clearer?

Tags: html, css

The text became invisible due to the background image, so I was wondering if there was a way to provide a background colour so that the text can be seen more clear.

I have attached a screenshot of the problem I am facing. Look at the bottom right to see my issue.

Would really appreciate your help.

[image: image to show what i mean]

Comment: If you can provide html and css, then it will be easy to tell!

Comment: And your research on how to set a background color with CSS yielded no results?

Comment: May you try background:hsl(0,0%,0%,0.5)

Comment: If you tell me which part of the html you would like to see I will attach it below @FareedKhan

Comment: Nope I couldn't find anything that satisfied my needs @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: is that in html or css? Sorry I'm not that good with html and css right now. @Dori

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52797690/8620333

Answer (score 0):

In css you can set a background-color attribute:

```css
p {
  background-color: #F00;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<p>Sample Text</p>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this slightly transparent? block color isnt what im looking for

Comment: @Anonymous then you can use `background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);` more info https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/