# Dynamic adaptation of the text color according to the color of the live background

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, sass

Hello I am currently developing a site, I am incorporating GRAY text with a BLACK and WHITE wallpaper (it is actually a starry background with the moon, stars and clouds, which moves from left to right ) the text remains perfectly visible however when a text is placed at the same level as the WHITE part (the moon) the text becomes difficult to read, even when the clouds pass under the GRAY text. Here is an image to help with the comprehension : [The moon hide the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkq8e.png) ( the cloud move ) [i need half black and half white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHBQv.png)

To try to solve this problem and for aesthetic reasons I tried to change the color of the text compared to the background color all this dynamically here is an example i found :

https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/

However I have not been able to adapt it to my project.

So how we can automatically switch to a darker version of the text depending on the brightness of images behind it ( here, when the text passes in front of the moon or when a cloud passes behind a text )

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52797690/8620333

Answer (score 0):

could you share some code snippet from your project?

I think it could be because your font has grey color, try changing it white.
Or you can try changing it to:

```
color: white;
mix-blend-mode: difference;
```

Comment: Let's reverse the problem to help with understanding. To read the text more easily when it is on a white background (here the moon or the clouds) I put it in black. However when the cloud moves and no longer locates under the text, the black text on black background is unreadable. the objective is that this black text gradually becomes white when it passes over the black background, and the other way around that it gradually turns black when it passes on the white background ( I will soon edit my post to try to explain it more simply )